# Object instantiation in C++ with type

Tags: c++

May someone tell me please why we do write `size_t` after `Graph` in the following line?

```
Graph<std::size_t> g;
```

`Graph` is a class name and `g` is an object. What does `size_t` do there? Why should we write that?

I am so sorry if the question is too basic. But I could not find explanation on this and so far when I've wanted to create an object of class I have written:

```
class_name object;
```

like:

```
Graph g;
```

Comment: `Graph` is probably not a class, but a [class template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template) that is [parametrized](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/compsystems/1989/win_stroustrup.pdf) by `std::size_t` type.

Comment: Have you used `std::vector`? It's the same story.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates

Comment: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @Evg Answer section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Graph` is a class template not an ordinary class.

Class templates define a class where the types of some of the variables, return types of methods, and/or parameters to the methods are specified as parameters.

Hence by using `Graph<std::size_t > g;` you are using one of the class template instantiation which has `size_t` as a type parameter.

You can use `Graph<int > g` too and so on.

An addition:

When the compiler encounters template method definitions, it performs syntax
checking ony, but doesn’t actually compile the templates.

Let us write the template

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass
{
    T memberVar{};
};
```

Only when the compiler encounters an instantiation of the template, such as `MyClass<int> myObj`, it writes code for an `int` version of the `MYClass` template by replacing each `T` in the class template definition with `int` and so on.

Comment: nitpick: Your wording can suggest class templates would be special kinds of classes. "Class templates define a class where .." strictly speaking a class template does not define a class, they are just templates, not classes. You only get a class definition once you instantiate the template